# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on boolean

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to figure out how to fix this error... I've seen other questions that have been closed but none of them have fixed my problem, I get that there's an issue with fetch_object() being boolean but I can't figure out why.

here's the my function:

```
function getNews($objCon, $page = null) {
    $sql = "SELECT id, headline, description FROM cms_news";
    if ($page) {
        $sql .= "WHERE cms_category_id = $page";
    }

    $objectResult = $objCon->query($sql);
    $news = [];
    while ($row = $objectResult->fetch_object()) {
        $news[$row->id] = $row;
    }
    return $news;
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Add a space. Guess where?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch\_object() on boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36147802/6521116)

Comment: @u_mulder you're making me feel dumb.. I can't figure out where

Comment: Answer is already telling that

Comment: @u_mulder thank you for the help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a space when you append your SQL:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, headline, description FROM cms_news ";

if ($page) {
    $sql .= "WHERE cms_category_id = $page";
}
```

Your previous SQL string would be:

```
SELECT id, headline, description FROM cms_newsWHERE cms_category_id = #
```

Comment: thanks for the help!!!